# Multi level cascade delete with the same types of entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following entities in domain project:

```
public class Parent {
    ...
    private Guid Id { get; private set; }

    private virtual Child Child { get; private set; }

    public void RemoveChild() {
        Child = null;
    }
    ...
}

public class Child {
    ...
    private Guid Id { get; private set; }

    private virtual Grandchild Grandchild1 { get; private set; }

    private virtual Grandchild Grandchild2 { get; private set; }
    ...
}

public class Grandchild {
    ...
    private Guid Id { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to set up Context (code first approach) in way where if I assign null to Child in Parent entity then Child and Grandchildren entities will be removed from database? I tried to set DeleteBehaviour.Cascade on Grandchild1Id and Grandchild2Id of Child but SQL Server don't allows to cascade delete of two the same types in entity.

I want to this scenario:

```
(Parent entity) Child = null =>
(Parent table) ChildId = NULL =>
(Child table) Grandchild1Id = NULL, Grandchild2Id = NULL =>
(Grandchild table) Deletes rows with Grandchild1Id AND Grandchild2Id
```

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I cannot use context in domain project (except abstraction but I dont know if it is a good idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

EDIT:

```
private void CascadeDelete(object item,DbContext dbContext)
{
    var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        object value = prop.GetValue(item);
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsInterface && value != null)
        {
            foreach (var iItem in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)value)
            {
                CascadeDelete(iItem);
            }
        }

        dbContext.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
CascadeDelete(ParentObj, dbContext);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I used it before for cascade insert or update

```
string PK = "Id";
int id = (int)item.GetType().GetProperty(PK).GetValue(item); // int? be better
if (id == 0)
{
    dbContext.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
}
else
{
    dbContext.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution but I dont want to add additional methods to my entities - they are domain classes and shouldn't be polluted because of infrastructure solutions

Comment: @vamteusz take a look im not sure what exactly you need

Comment: Hmm... Thats interesting. Im think that it is able to set by overriding save changes and detect null entities then delete all child entities. Thanks!

Comment: I use it before to cascade insert OR update for multidimensional model. Like when you want to save parent with childs at once. Because this normally causing huge issue. EF is always inserting all childs never update old.